# Amount of RAM went down when I installed more?

Tags: windows, memory, hardware-failure, ddr

I have an old PC that I would like to use as a home file server. The amount of RAM it had was very low (somewhere around 500mb), so I decided to add some more. I got the exact same kind it uses (DDR400), and put it in. When I booted it up to see if I did it right, it had actually decreased to 248mb! I had some trouble installing it, the white latches would not click down no matter how hard I pushed on it. But the other older RAM stick in there also doesn't have the latches clicked and it still worked. I also tried putting the old one back in, and that didn't work anymore. Did I install it wrong or what? It's a Gateway E-Series. Couldn't find an exact model number.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you broke it. You should not have needed to use force. There should never be any reason to apply power with the RAM facing the wrong way.

Comment: The RAM itself or the holder? EDIT: I didn't turn it on with it facing the wrong way. Even a noob like me knows that's dumb.

Comment: It's hard to be sure. You can break pretty much anything with enough force. I'm glad you didn't apply power with the RAM facing the wrong way. I'd suggest you remove all the RAM, inspect both the RAM sticks and the pins to make sure they're undamaged, then test each RAM stick individually in each slot to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Alright. It seemed like only the right side wasn't going in. The left _almost_ goes in. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Sams I often find that one side will click down and the other won't all the way on the first try. BE CAREFUL NOT TO BREAK IT, but your fingers will hurt in order to apply the needed force. Press on both ends, rather than in the middle.

Comment: Take out an old stick of RAM and a new stick.  Place one on top of the other, if the notch doesnt line up, you have the wrong type of memory.

Comment: @SamS It sounds like it's not the right type of memory then.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The old stick didn't go back in either.